# Show that m has to be even if for every integer $a$, $a^m\equiv1\pmod{n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $m$ be an integer such that $a^m\equiv1\pmod{n}$ for every integer $a\ \epsilon\ (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$. Show that $m$ is even.

I know that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$ by Euler's Theorem, so is this question then just about showing that $\phi(n)$ is even?

Comment: Well, just take $a=n-1$.

Comment: it's supposed to be true for every $a\ \epsilon\ (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$

Comment: Right.  So in particular it must be true for $n-1$.  (note:  I think you meant to write "for every $a\in \left(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\right)^*$".  it's obviously necessary to stick with $a$ relatively prime to $n$.).

Comment: @lulu Same concept, I just think using $-1$ as the coset representative is more intuitive.

Comment: @DonThousand  You are probably right about that...not sure why I went for $n-1$ instead.  So, I agree.  Just take $a=-1$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to just show that $m$ must be even for $a=-1$? And yes I did mean $ a\epsilon(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$ before, sorry about the typo.

Comment: Is that sufficient because we know some $m$ does exist (namely $\phi(n)$)? And thus if $m$ is even for $a=-1$, $\phi(n)$ must also be even?

Comment: If you know both $a^m\equiv1$ and $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1$ for all $a$ then how does that imply that $m=\phi(n)$?

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is one such number but it  need not be the only one. (If $n = 21$ then $m = 6\ne \phi(21)=12$ is one.)  However once you show that *any* $m$ must be even that means $\phi(n)$ will be even as well (as it is such a number).  ... Um... I think $n > 2$ has to also be a requirement:  $a^1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for all $a \in (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^*$ but $1$ isn't even.  (If $n=2$ then $-1 \equiv 1$.  But if $n >2$ then $-1 \not \equiv 1$.)

Comment: But you can't go the other way.  If one such number is even you can not conclude all such numbers are even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, $a\equiv -1$  suffices. Because, modular arithmetic, obeys normal arithmetic rules mostly (otherwise it would be useless in diophantine equation analysis).  $$(-1)^{2x+1}=-1$$ is one such rule. So m can't be odd, and work in this case. No need to get anything else involved.

**Exception** n=2 and n=1 though. Because  then 1 and -1 are congruent.

Comment: But $m$ can be odd if $\,n = 2,\,$ e.g. $\,a^1\equiv 1\pmod{\!2}\,$ for all $\,a\,$ coprime to $2$ $\ \ $

Comment: okay yes mod 2 is a special case, because $1\equiv -1$